# Running 'top' in thread produces SIGTTOU

Tags: python, multithreading, signals, freebsd, top-command

For reasons I won't go into, I need to run a variant of 'top -m io -d 2 10' within a subprocess from a Python thread on FreeBSD 8.1. The trouble is, it seems that sometimes SIGTTOU gets produced (under certain code-dependent conditions that I haven't yet deciphered), halting top and the thread entirely. Other times, it seems that SIGTTOU is not produced, but top or the thread get stuck anyway.

The output from top should produce two sets of IO stats for the top 10 processes on the system, where the first set is "absolute" numbers and the second set is the incremental difference of the stats since the last set, one second earlier. Running this command on the terminal or within a shell script, whether redirecting the output or not, works fine.

When the problem occurs, it seems that 'top' writes the first set of outputs, but then hangs/receives SIGTTOU before it can output the second set. In the sample code below, only one set of process stats is written to the output file.

I discovered the SIGTTOU signal running the python script under 'truss', but it seems that interactions between 'truss' and 'top' themselves may be a confounding matter, since simply running `truss top -d 2` produces the signal and hangs, as below:

```
...
ioctl(1,TIOCGETA,0xffffe460)             = 0 (0x0)
ioctl(1,TIOCGETA,0xc6b138)           = 0 (0x0)
ioctl(1,TIOCGETA,0xffffe410)             = 0 (0x0)
ioctl(1,TIOCGWINSZ,0xffffe460)           = 0 (0x0)
ioctl(1,TIOCGWINSZ,0xffffe930)           = 0 (0x0)
ioctl(1,TIOCGETA,0x50e560)           = 0 (0x0)
sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,SIGINT|SIGQUIT|SIGTSTP,0x0) = 0 (0x0)
ioctl(1,TIOCGETA,0x50e560)           = 0 (0x0)
SIGNAL 22 (SIGTTOU)
```

Here's a sample Python script that reproduces the hang and/or SIGTTOU:

```
import subprocess
from threading import Thread

def run():
    with open("top.log", "wb") as f:
        subprocess.Popen(("/usr/bin/top", "-m", "io", "-d", "2", "10"), stdout=f, stderr=f, stdin=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    th = Thread(target=run)
    print "Starting"
    th.start()
    th.join()
```

On my last run through, this sample program did not produce SIGTTOU, but top did hang. Truss shows:

```
....
open("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/_heapq.pyc",O_RDONLY,0666) ERR#2 'No such file or directory'
stat("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_heapq",0x7fffffffa500) ERR#2 'No such file or directory'
open("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_heapq.so",O_RDONLY,0666) = 5 (0x5)
fstat(5,{ mode=-rwxr-xr-x ,inode=238187,size=22293,blksize=16384 }) = 0 (0x0)
sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,SIGHUP|SIGINT|SIGQUIT|SIGKILL|SIGPIPE|SIGALRM|SIGTERM|SIGURG|SIGSTOP|SIGTSTP|SIGCONT|SIGCHLD|SIGTTIN|SIGTTOU|SIGIO|SIGXCPU|SIGXFSZ|SIGVTALRM|SIGPROF|SIGWINCH|SIGINFO|SIGUSR1|SIGUSR2,0x0) = 0 (0x0)
open("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_heapq.so",O_RDONLY,057) = 6 (0x6)
fstat(6,{ mode=-rwxr-xr-x ,inode=238187,size=22293,blksize=16384 }) = 0 (0x0)
pread(0x6,0x80074c2e0,0x1000,0x0,0xffff800800653120,0x8080808080808080) = 4096 (0x1000)
mmap(0x0,1069056,PROT_NONE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON|MAP_NOCORE,-1,0x0) = 34389442560 (0x801c54000)
mmap(0x801c54000,12288,PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_NOCORE,6,0x0) = 34389442560 (0x801c54000)
mmap(0x801d56000,12288,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED,6,0x2000) = 34390499328 (0x801d56000)
mmap(0x0,36864,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON,-1,0x0) = 34366377984 (0x800655000)
close(6)                     = 0 (0x0)
mmap(0x0,832,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_ANON,-1,0x0) = 34366414848 (0x80065e000)
munmap(0x80065e000,832)              = 0 (0x0)
sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,0x0,0x0)         = 0 (0x0)
sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,SIGHUP|SIGINT|SIGQUIT|SIGKILL|SIGPIPE|SIGALRM|SIGTERM|SIGURG|SIGSTOP|SIGTSTP|SIGCONT|SIGCHLD|SIGTTIN|SIGTTOU|SIGIO|SIGXCPU|SIGXFSZ|SIGVTALRM|SIGPROF|SIGWINCH|SIGINFO|SIGUSR1|SIGUSR2,0x0) = 0 (0x0)
sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,0x0,0x0)         = 0 (0x0)
close(5)                     = 0 (0x0)
close(4)                     = 0 (0x0)
close(3)                     = 0 (0x0)
close(2)                     = 0 (0x0)
fstat(1,{ mode=crw------- ,inode=102,size=0,blksize=4096 }) = 0 (0x0)
ioctl(1,TIOCGETA,0xffffe400)             = 0 (0x0)
Starting
write(1,"Starting\n",9)              = 9 (0x9)
sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,SIGHUP|SIGINT|SIGQUIT|SIGILL|SIGTRAP|SIGABRT|SIGEMT|SIGFPE|SIGKILL|SIGBUS|SIGSEGV|SIGSYS|SIGPIPE|SIGALRM|SIGTERM|SIGURG|SIGSTOP|SIGTSTP|SIGCONT|SIGCHLD|SIGTTIN|SIGTTOU|SIGIO|SIGXCPU|SIGXFSZ|SIGVTALRM|SIGPROF|SIGWINCH|SIGINFO|SIGUSR1|SIGUSR2,0x0) = 0 (0x0)
_umtx_op(0x7fffffffe1d8,0x3,0x1,0x0,0x0,0x0)     = 0 (0x0)
sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,SIGHUP|SIGINT|SIGQUIT|SIGABRT|SIGEMT|SIGKILL|SIGSYS|SIGPIPE|SIGALRM|SIGTERM|SIGURG|SIGSTOP|SIGTSTP|SIGCONT|SIGCHLD|SIGTTIN|SIGTTOU|SIGIO|SIGXCPU|SIGXFSZ|SIGVTALRM|SIGPROF|SIGWINCH|SIGINFO|SIGUSR1|SIGUSR2,SIGHUP|SIGINT|SIGQUIT|SIGILL|SIGTRAP|SIGABRT|SIGEMT|SIGFPE|SIGBUS|SIGSEGV|SIGSYS|SIGPIPE|SIGALRM|SIGTERM|SIGURG|SIGTSTP|SIGCONT|SIGCHLD|SIGTTIN|SIGTTOU|SIGIO|SIGXCPU|SIGXFSZ|SIGVTALRM|SIGPROF|SIGWINCH|SIGINFO|SIGUSR1|SIGUSR2) = 0 (0x0)
sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,SIGHUP|SIGINT|SIGQUIT|SIGILL|SIGTRAP|SIGABRT|SIGEMT|SIGFPE|SIGBUS|SIGSEGV|SIGSYS|SIGPIPE|SIGALRM|SIGTERM|SIGURG|SIGTSTP|SIGCONT|SIGCHLD|SIGTTIN|SIGTTOU|SIGIO|SIGXCPU|SIGXFSZ|SIGVTALRM|SIGPROF|SIGWINCH|SIGINFO|SIGUSR1|SIGUSR2,0x0) = 0 (0x0)
sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,SIGHUP|SIGINT|SIGQUIT|SIGABRT|SIGEMT|SIGKILL|SIGSYS|SIGPIPE|SIGALRM|SIGTERM|SIGURG|SIGSTOP|SIGTSTP|SIGCONT|SIGCHLD|SIGTTIN|SIGTTOU|SIGIO|SIGXCPU|SIGXFSZ|SIGVTALRM|SIGPROF|SIGWINCH|SIGINFO|SIGUSR1|SIGUSR2,SIGHUP|SIGINT|SIGQUIT|SIGILL|SIGTRAP|SIGABRT|SIGEMT|SIGFPE|SIGBUS|SIGSEGV|SIGSYS|SIGPIPE|SIGALRM|SIGTERM|SIGURG|SIGTSTP|SIGCONT|SIGCHLD|SIGTTIN|SIGTTOU|SIGIO|SIGXCPU|SIGXFSZ|SIGVTALRM|SIGPROF|SIGWINCH|SIGINFO|SIGUSR1|SIGUSR2) = 0 (0x0)
sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,SIGHUP|SIGINT|SIGQUIT|SIGILL|SIGTRAP|SIGABRT|SIGEMT|SIGFPE|SIGBUS|SIGSEGV|SIGSYS|SIGPIPE|SIGALRM|SIGTERM|SIGURG|SIGTSTP|SIGCONT|SIGCHLD|SIGTTIN|SIGTTOU|SIGIO|SIGXCPU|SIGXFSZ|SIGVTALRM|SIGPROF|SIGWINCH|SIGINFO|SIGUSR1|SIGUSR2,0x0) = 0 (0x0)
mmap(0x7fffffbde000,135168,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_STACK,-1,0x0) = 140737484021760 (0x7fffffbde000)
mprotect(0x7fffffbde000,4096,PROT_NONE)      = 0 (0x0)
thr_new(0x7fffffffe220,0x68,0x800a9f4c0,0x186fc,0xffffffff,0x0) = 0 (0x0)
sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,0x0,0x0)         = 0 (0x0)
mmap(0x0,2097152,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON,-1,0x0) = 34390511616 (0x801d59000)
mmap(0x801f59000,684032,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON,-1,0x0) = 34392608768 (0x801f59000)
munmap(0x801d59000,684032)           = 0 (0x0)
_umtx_op(0x8010127f8,0x10,0x1,0x0,0x0,0x0)   = 0 (0x0)
_umtx_op(0x800e0b438,0xf,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0)    = 0 (0x0)
_umtx_op(0x800e0b438,0x10,0x1,0x0,0x0,0x0)   = 0 (0x0)
_umtx_op(0x800e0b438,0x10,0x1,0x0,0x0,0x0)   = 0 (0x0)
_umtx_op(0x800e0b438,0x10,0x1,0x0,0x0,0x8080808080808080) = 0 (0x0)
open("top.log",O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC,0666)    = 2 (0x2)
fstat(2,{ mode=-rw-r--r-- ,inode=70860,size=0,blksize=16384 }) = 0 (0x0)
pipe(0x7fffffbfd910)                 = 0 (0x0)
pipe(0x7fffffbfd870)                 = 0 (0x0)
fcntl(6,F_GETFD,)                = 0 (0x0)
fcntl(6,F_SETFD,FD_CLOEXEC)          = 0 (0x0)
sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,SIGHUP|SIGINT|SIGQUIT|SIGABRT|SIGEMT|SIGKILL|SIGSYS|SIGPIPE|SIGALRM|SIGTERM|SIGURG|SIGSTOP|SIGTSTP|SIGCONT|SIGCHLD|SIGTTIN|SIGTTOU|SIGIO|SIGXCPU|SIGXFSZ|SIGVTALRM|SIGPROF|SIGWINCH|SIGINFO|SIGUSR1|SIGUSR2,SIGHUP|SIGINT|SIGQUIT|SIGILL|SIGTRAP|SIGABRT|SIGEMT|SIGFPE|SIGBUS|SIGSEGV|SIGSYS|SIGPIPE|SIGALRM|SIGTERM|SIGURG|SIGTSTP|SIGCONT|SIGCHLD|SIGTTIN|SIGTTOU|SIGIO|SIGXCPU|SIGXFSZ|SIGVTALRM|SIGPROF|SIGWINCH|SIGINFO|SIGUSR1|SIGUSR2) = 0 (0x0)
fork()                       = 21503 (0x53ff)
sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,SIGHUP|SIGINT|SIGQUIT|SIGILL|SIGTRAP|SIGABRT|SIGEMT|SIGFPE|SIGBUS|SIGSEGV|SIGSYS|SIGPIPE|SIGALRM|SIGTERM|SIGURG|SIGTSTP|SIGCONT|SIGCHLD|SIGTTIN|SIGTTOU|SIGIO|SIGXCPU|SIGXFSZ|SIGVTALRM|SIGPROF|SIGWINCH|SIGINFO|SIGUSR1|SIGUSR2,0x0) = 0 (0x0)
close(6)                     = 0 (0x0)
close(3)                     = 0 (0x0)
read(5,0x801e31024,1048576)          = 0 (0x0)
close(5)                     = 0 (0x0)
fcntl(4,F_GETFL,)                = 2 (0x2)
fstat(4,{ mode=p--------- ,inode=0,size=0,blksize=4096 }) = 0 (0x0)
close(4)                     = 0 (0x0)
```

I've looked into SIGTTOU and found references to the TOSTOP termios flag, and I've fiddled with it in the main thread, in the child thread, and in the environment invoking Python, all to no avail. It's been an educational process, but I'm not there yet.

I've run tests to make sure that the top process is created in and appears to stay in the process group of the Python process (based on the SIGTTOU documentation, if it weren't, this would be the reason for SIGTTOU), and that seems fine: the PGRP ends up being the same as the Python PID/PGRP.

I've tried running 'top' with subprocess.check_output and with .Popen() using shell=True, shell=False, and redirecting std{out,err,in} all over the place, none of which seems to change this end result. I've tried running 'top' using a '/bin/sh -c' command executed through subprocess, also to no avail.

Without doing something semi-weird like running 'top' within a shell script which my Python thread invokes, or resorting to os.fork() instead of using threading, how can I get around this issue, and what's the root cause?

Answer (score 2):

I realize that this question is a bit old, but if you're still running into errors, I'd love to debug this into the dirt.

**Root cause**: Your SIGTTOU is occurring because your Python interpreter is forking to create the background thread when you call `th = Thread(target=run)` and `top` hasn't been told/doesn't know it shouldn't be using the terminal.  You are seeing signals because `top` is getting frisky and trying to write to the terminal (or change its emulation mode) as a *background* process when you have disallowed this behavior from occurring in your TTY settings.

`man stty` explains this more succinctly than I would:

```
 tostop (-tostop)
             Send (do not send) SIGTTOU for background output.  This causes back-
             ground jobs to stop if they attempt terminal output.
```

**Workaround**: Allow background threads to throw output onto the terminal during the run of your script (`stty -tostop; python my_script.py; stty tostop`) or add the (`'-n'`) flag to your subprocess call of `top`.

---

Elaboration:  *Only one* process per group can be in the foreground and the rest remain in the background -- the *foreground* process handles I/O from a tty and the rest must remain as *background* processes or you'll see job control signals start getting thrown (e.g. SIGTTIN/SIGTTOU).

During the execution of your Python script, I believe the following occurs:

```
$SHELL #(controls TTY)
$ python my_script.py #(tcsetpgrp() is called to hand off control of TTY)
~~~ heck yeah, snake party ~~~
th = Thread(target=run) #(run target=proc in background)
print "Starting" #(still okay -- this gets handed up to the foreground interpreter)
th.start() 
#(here be dragons, std i/o in background fork)
subprocess.Popen(("/usr/bin/top", "-m", "io", "-d", "2", "10").communicate()
```

I checked out the [FreeBSD manual for its top implementation](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?top) and I found the following smoking gun:

```
DESCRIPTION
       Top displays the top processes on the system and  periodically  updates
       this  information...

       Top makes a distinction between terminals that support  advanced  capa-
       bilities and those that do not...If the output of top is redi-
       rected to a file, it acts as if it were being run on a dumb terminal.

 ...
 OPTIONS
   -i     Use  "interactive" mode.  In this mode, any input is immediately
      read for processing.  See the section on "Interactive Mode"  for
      an  explanation of which keys perform what functions.  After the
      command is processed, the screen will  immediately  be  updated,
      even  if  the  command  was  not  understood.   This mode is the
      default when standard output is an intelligent terminal.
   ...
   -n     Use  "non-interactive" mode.  This is identical to "batch" mode.
```

Whereas `top` doesn't know that it's being run in a background process (the file handing is being done with your Python context manager) and you didn't specify non-interactive mode, it's assuming that it's free to use the tty -- meaning that you'll probably see SIGTTIN signals if `top` gets ahold of any STDIN and SIGTTOU signals when commands are processed and it tries to update the screen.

Of particular interest from FreeBSD's top implementation, the difference in what happens when called interactively or not:

- [Flags being parsed](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/contrib/top/top.c#L329-L332)
- [See differences in function calls for non-interactive](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/contrib/top/top.c#L741-L748)

Your idea to add `shell=True` verifies this theory as it [sets the child process of 'top' to the PID of the shell that `subprocess.Popen(..)` spawns](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.pid), which is still in a background Python thread.

(n.b. apologies: I don't have access to a FreeBSD 8.1 host to verify behavior on your host OS right now.)

Answer (score 1):

`SIGTTOU` is used when a process attempts to change the controlling terminal:

> If the implementation supports job-control, unless otherwise noted, processes in a background process-group are restricted in their use of the terminal-control-functions (see termios(3C)). Attempts to perform these functions cause the process-group to be sent the signal SIGTTOU. If the calling process either ignores or blocks the signal SIGTTOU, attempting to perform a control-function proceeds without sending the signal SIGTTOU.

(From [Terminal access control](http://uw714doc.sco.com/en/SDK_sysprog/SJCP_TermAccCntl.html))

What does this mean? It means top is trying to change something about the Terminal and is getting told that it can't do that, and the default action for `SIGTTOU` is to stop the process from running (the hang as you call it).

What you could try to do is use `fork()` to get it into its own process group, one without a controlling terminal. This should allow `top` to call whatever it wants to call, and since there is no controlling terminal it will simply have no effect.

However top was never meant to be called non-interactively, are you not able to get the same information using `ps`?

---

This blog post: http://www.technovelty.org/tips/sigttou-and-switching-to-canonical-mode.html also explains what is going on in a clear manner. Hope it helps.

Comment: That matches what I've discovered since then. To this day though I'm still not sure what top is trying to modify about the terminal (or why). Unfortunately I'm working this into a legacy system, so I actually need to produce the raw output of `top` in my code. I ended up working around this by using Python's `pty` library and running top inside that. Due to other technical difficulties however, this also meant having to minimally parse and strip ANSI sequences from the output. (But it works now!) :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the -b option with top? It is meant for batch-jobs and dumb terminals and may tell top to not do, whatever it is doing that triggers the signal...